# Illegal string offset in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using codeigniter to develop a property management system. I'm getting illegel offset error for each  $data[''] i have defined in a function in the controller. Other functions in the same controller works fine without any problem. I tried exisitng answers provided for 'illegel offest ' error but none of those answered my problem. Here is my code:-

Model (model_season.php):-

```
            function insertSeason($data){

            $season_flag = '';

            $this->db->insert("season",$data);


            if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0){

                    $season_flag = true;
           } else {

                    $season_flag = false;
           }

               return $season_flag;

         }




       function getAllSeason(){


        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('season');
        $this->db->join('property', 'property.PropertyID = season.SeasonID', 'inner');
        $this->db->order_by('season.SeasonID', 'DESC');

        //$this->db->from('season');
        //$this->db->order_by("SeasonID", "DESC");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

        
        }
```

Here is the controller (season.php):-

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Season extends CI_Controller{



    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_season');
        $this->load->model('model_property');
        $this->load->model('user');

        
     }


     function index(){

            if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            {
                $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        
                $this->lang->load('common');
                $this->lang->load('season');

                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['user_name']          = $session_data['user_name'];
                $data['property_list']      = $this->model_property->GetAllProperty();
                $data['season_list']        = $this->model_season->getAllSeason();


                $this->load->view('backend/header');
                $this->load->view('backend/add_season_view',$data);
                $this->load->view('backend/footer');


            } else {

                redirect('login', 'refresh');
            }
     }





      function navigateToSeason($data_){



            if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            {


                


                $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        
                $this->lang->load('common');
                $this->lang->load('season');

                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['user_name']          = $session_data['user_name'];
                $data['property_list']      = $this->model_property->GetAllProperty();
                //var_dump($this->model_season->getAllSeason());
                $data['season_list']        = $this->model_season->getAllSeason();

                if ($data_ == 1){
                $data['message'] = "success";
                }
                if ($data_ == 0){
                        $data['message'] = "error..";
                }

                
                $this->load->view('backend/header');
                $this->load->view('backend/add_season_view',$data);
                $this->load->view('backend/footer');


            } else {

                redirect('login', 'refresh');
            }
     }

     function addSeason(){

                echo 'function test pass..';


                $username = $this->input->post('username');

                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $validaton_options = array (

                            array(

                                        'field' => 'season_selected_property',
                                        'label' => 'Property',
                                        'rules' => 'trim|numeric|required|xss_clean'
                                ),



                            array(

                                        'field' => 'season_title',
                                        'label' => 'Season Title',
                                        'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
                                ),



                            array(

                                        'field' => 'season_start_date',
                                        'label' => 'Season start date',
                                        'rules' => 'trim|required|callback_date_valid'
                                ),



                            array(

                                        'field' => 'season_end_date',
                                        'label' => 'Season end date',
                                        'rules' => 'trim|required|callback_date_valid'
                                )
                    );


                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($validaton_options);


                    //start form validation
                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true){

                                
                                $NewSeason = array(

                                        "SeasonPropertyID"=> $this->input->post('season_selected_property'),
                                        "SeasonTitle"=>$this->input->post('season_title'),
                                        "StartDate"=>$this->input->post('season_start_date'),
                                        "EndDate"=>$this->input->post('season_end_date')


                                );


                                //check - add to database
                                if ($this->model_season->insertSeason($NewSeason)){     

                                        redirect('season/navigateToSeason/1','refresh');


                                } else {

                                        redirect('season/navigateToSeason/0','refresh');

                                }
                                // end database add






                    } else {

                        
                                            if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
                                            {
                                                $this->load->helper(array('form'));
                                        
                                                $this->lang->load('common');
                                                $this->lang->load('season');

                                                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                                                $data['user_name'] = $session_data['user_name'];
                                                $data['property_list']      = $this->model_property->GetAllProperty();
                                                $data['season_list']        = $this->model_season->getAllSeason();
                                                

                                                $this->load->view('backend/header');
                                                $this->load->view('backend/add_season_view',$data);
                                                $this->load->view('backend/footer');


                                            } else {

                                                redirect('login', 'refresh');
                                            }

                    }
                    //end form validation


     }//end function



     public function date_valid($date)
    {
            $parts = explode("-", $date);
            if (count($parts) == 3) {      
                    if (checkdate($parts[1], $parts[2], $parts[0]))
                    {
                        return TRUE;
                    }
            }
            
            $this->form_validation->set_message('date_valid', 'The Date field must be yyyy-mm-dd');

            return false;
    }









}


?>
```

Here is my view:-

```
  <?php if (isset($message)  && $message != ''){

                echo  $message;
            }


       if (isset($user_name) && $user_name != ''){
                  echo $user_name;
       }




         if (isset($season_list))
         {  


                       foreach ($season_list as $season){


                                        echo $season->SeasonTitle; 
                                        echo $season->StartDate; 
                                        echo $season->EndDate; 
                       }


          }

 ?>
```

These are my errors:-

### A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'user_name'

Filename: controllers/season.php

Line Number: 65

### A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'property_list'

Filename: controllers/season.php

Line Number: 66

### A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: controllers/season.php

Line Number: 66

### A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'message'

Filename: controllers/season.php

Line Number: 70"

Var Dumb Result  - var_dump($this->model_season->getAllSeason()):

```
 array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#42 (29) { ["SeasonID"]=> string(1) "2" ["SeasonPropertyID"]=> string(2) "14" ["SeasonTitle"]=> string(6) "ghfghf" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "2014-11-24" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "2014-11-30" ["PropertyID"]=> string(1) "2" ["Title"]=> string(16) "Hill Apartment" ["Description"]=> string(562) "In March 2014, Nayon â€œ â€ Fonseka, re-established Lake House, a 13-room Bed & Breakfast / Budget Hotel, that has been owned by her family for 40 years. Down a quiet residential lane in the heart of commercial city, Lake House was one of the first accredited tourist accommodations in the Island, which   refurbished with her usual creative flair. Conceived as a â€˜home away from homeâ€™ while in the Island, whether for a few days of holiday or a month on business, Lake House is ideally located and run in an unobtrusive, yet professional manner." ["StarRating"]=> string(1) "4" ["GoogleMapURL"]=> string(25) "https://goo.gl/maps/xKwPQ" ["Address"]=> string(20) "alvo Terrace, Kandy" ["Telephone"]=> string(11) "94112326443" ["Fax"]=> string(11) "94112326443" ["TripAdvisorURL"]=> string(116) "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g293962-d586475-Reviews- _Villas_Lake_Lodge-city_Western_Province.html" ["ThumbNail1"]=> string(6) "DD.jpg" ["ThumbNail2"]=> string(0) "" ["ThumbNail3"]=> string(0) "" ["WebSiteURL"]=> string(18) "www. villas.com" ["Email"]=> string(24) "lakelodge@ villas.com" ["TaxChargesPercentage"]=> string(1) "2" ["TaxDescription"]=> string(60) "This includes service charges and the Island Government taxes" ["Enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["DateCreated"]=> string(10) "2014-10-31" ["CreatedBy"]=> string(8) " vila" ["LastModified"]=> string(10) "2014-11-05" ["ModifiedBy"]=> string(8) " vila" ["ExtraBedPrice"]=> string(3) "120" ["Direction"]=> string(477) "Lake House is situated down alvo terrace off alvo place. You have to access it through Perehera Mawatha, which is off Sir James Pieris Mawatha (this is the road going towards the Nawaloka hospital). On Perahera Mawatha, passing Bishopâ€™s College auditorium is a playground, you take the first turn on to your left after you pass the playground, which is alvo Place. Down alvo Place the first turn to your left is alvo terrace, the hotel is right at the bottom of the lane" ["ExtraBed"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#41 (29) { ["SeasonID"]=> string(1) "1" ["SeasonPropertyID"]=> string(2) "25" ["SeasonTitle"]=> string(10) "Off Season" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "2014-11-10" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "2014-11-24" ["PropertyID"]=> string(1) "1" ["Title"]=> string(8) "DD Lodge" ["Description"]=> string(562) "In March 2014, Nayon â€œ â€ Fonseka, re-established Lake House, a 13-room Bed & Breakfast / Budget Hotel, that has been owned by her family for 40 years. Down a quiet residential lane in the heart of commercial city, Lake House was one of the first accredited tourist accommodations in the Island, which   refurbished with her usual creative flair. Conceived as a â€˜home away from homeâ€™ while in the Island, whether for a few days of holiday or a month on business, Lake House is ideally located and run in an unobtrusive, yet professional manner." ["StarRating"]=> string(1) "3" ["GoogleMapURL"]=> string(25) "https://goo.gl/maps/xKwPQ" ["Address"]=> string(30) "alvo Terrace, city 3 00300" ["Telephone"]=> string(11) "94112326443" ["Fax"]=> string(11) "94112326443" ["TripAdvisorURL"]=> string(116) "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g293962-d586475-Reviews- _Villas_Lake_Lodge-city_Western_Province.html" ["ThumbNail1"]=> string(7) "LL1.jpg" ["ThumbNail2"]=> string(1) "0" ["ThumbNail3"]=> string(1) "0" ["WebSiteURL"]=> string(18) "www. villas.com" ["Email"]=> string(24) "lakelodge@ villas.com" ["TaxChargesPercentage"]=> string(1) "2" ["TaxDescription"]=> string(60) "This includes service charges and the Island Government taxes" ["Enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["DateCreated"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["CreatedBy"]=> string(0) "" ["LastModified"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["ModifiedBy"]=> string(0) "" ["ExtraBedPrice"]=> string(1) "0" ["Direction"]=> string(477) "Lake House is situated down alvo terrace off alvo place. You have to access it through Perehera Mawatha, which is off Sir James Pieris Mawatha (this is the road going towards the Nawaloka hospital). On Perahera Mawatha, passing Bishopâ€™s College auditorium is a playground, you take the first turn on to your left after you pass the playground, which is alvo Place. Down alvo Place the first turn to your left is alvo terrace, the hotel is right at the bottom of the lane" ["ExtraBed"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved. The issue was parameter in the function navigateToSeason($data) in my controller. I renamed the perameter $data to $data_ and it works smoothly now. Please make sure to choose a different parameter name for each function.